# Setting shared ptrs to null

Tags: c++

Say i have a class Character and I have:

```
shared_ptr<Character> c;
```

As a field in class `A`. In the constructor of `A`, can I do this:

```
A::A(..):c{nullptr}
```

Is this valid? How do I properly initialize a shared ptr in MIL then?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you dont need to do anything.

Comment: What is `MIL` ?

Comment: You need to be aware that (unlike basic types) class types are already implicitly default-initialised, so you don't actually have to do anything yourself.

Comment: @user2079303 Member Initialization List, I suppose.

Comment: @Quentin Ah. seems likely given the context.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need even to explicitly set `c` to `nullptr`, though your code is valid.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) you might see a list of available constructors. Constructors:

```
constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;
constexpr shared_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;
```

do the same thing:

> Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty shared_ptr

so default initialization of `c` is pretty good and should work for you too.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this valid? How do I properly initialize a shared ptr in MIL then?

Yes as stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) initializing `std::shared_ptr` by `nullptr` is prefectly valid. Note you can achieve the same using default constructor, but if you find this way more readable it initializes `std::shared_ptr` the same way:

> 1-2) Constructs a shared_ptr with no managed object, i.e. empty
>   shared_ptr

Answer (score 2):

> Setting shared ptrs to null
>
> ```
> c{nullptr}
> ```
>
> Is this valid?

Yes. That will call the `shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)` constructor.

Other possibility is value initialization, which calls the default constructor: `c()`.

Or simply don't have an entry in the member initialization list. Members that lack entry in the member initialization list and don't have a brace-initializer are default initialized. Default initialized class objects are initialized with the default constructor. Then, you don't need to have a user defined constructor at all. The implicitly generated one default initializes all members, which may be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use empty braces:

```
A::A() :
c()
{
}
```

This will [default initialise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) the instance.

Or forgo the initialisation completely.

`A::A() = default` or just delete the constructor completely.

Comment: Do you have to mention `c` at all?

Comment: If all member-variables should be default-constructed/-initialized, no `A` constructor is needed at all. Or possibly explicitly use the `default` designator for it.